# Why Ruby's strftime is rounding up the date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Ruby on Rails project. Let's say I have a table `items` in my database with a column called `expiry_date`.

Consider these two records from the `items` table:

1. `id: 1, expiry_date: 2020-12-25 23:29:00` (assume that I loaded this into the instance variable `@item_one` as an ActiveRecord object)
2. `id: 2, expiry_date: 2020-12-25 12:29:00` (assume that I loaded this into the instance variable `@item_two` as an ActiveRecord object)

Why did the `strftime` method gives me this (I expect both of them to evaluate to `25 December 2020`?

`@item_one.expiry_date.strftime('%-d %B %Y')` evaluates to `26 December 2020`
`@item_two.expiry_date.strftime('%-d %B %Y')` evaluates to `25 December 2020`

Comment: looks like something with the Timezones. Probably the non timezoned expiry date gets then timezoned before it gets strftimed. It's just a guess, you would need to add more info to the question to really know for sure.

Comment: What's the value of `@item_one.expiry_date` and `@item_two.expiry_date`? (including timezone)

Comment: **Timezones**  -- What timezone is the date stored in? What timezone is your server running in?

Comment: BTW, why does a column called `expiry_date` have a time part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out in the end.

The timezone of my machine is GMT+8.

The dates in my question was directly taken from the database and when I `strftime`d it adds 8 hours to the time part, hence rounding up the date.

Comment: When you write a time / date to the database, Rails converts it to UTC. Likewise, it converts it back to your machine's timezone when reading it from the database. That conversion happens before calling `strftime` – your `@item_one.expiry_date` is already in GMT+8.